# SSH authorized key command bypass with X11 forwarding

Tags: ssh, security

On a server's `authorized_keys` file, an ssh key is preceded by a specific command to prevent users to run any other command:

```
command="/bin/restricted_shell" ssh-rsa AAA....
```

It is often recommended to add the `no-X11-forwarding` restriction when using command.

As the restriction is not present - and `X11Forwarding` is allowed - is it possible to execute for instance an `xterm` session instead of the restricted command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As the restriction is not present - and X11Forwarding is allowed - is it possible to execute for instance an xterm session instead of the restricted command?

No, it's not possible.

But, unless the forced command specified needs itself an X11 display, there's no reason to allow the X11 forwarding: when X11 forwarding is enabled, ssh will run the `xauth` command on the server, which will create/modify an `.Xauthority` file in the user's directory, so an innocuous entry like `command="uptime" ssh-rsa ...` in the authorized keys file suddenly becomes a lot more interesting, and somebody may *leverage* it in creative ways.

Notice that you can disable X11 forwarding on a per-key basis in the authorized keys file:

```
command="uptime",no-x11-forwarding ssh-rsa AAA...
```